# Excel VBA: Timer prevents drag and drop functionality?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently wrote a workbook macro to close the workbook after a certain time.  It has a timer running in the background.  I can enter information into cells normally but if I drag a cell to another location, it just disappears and there is no "undo" option.  If I enter debug mode or stop the macro and restart it, drag and drop functionality works again.  But on normal workbook open, it does not.  Any ideas on how to work around this?

I tried forcing Application.CellDragAndDrop = True but this did not fix the problem.
The only way drag and drop starts working correctly is if I stop the macro, then manually start it.
Code is below.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Start, TimeInMinutes, UserAck

TimeInMinutes = 5 'Timer is set for 5 minutes; change as needed.

If UserAck = 0 Then
UserAck = MsgBox("This file will automatically close after " & TimeInMinutes & " minutes.", 0)
End If

Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Start = Timer 'Grab current time stamp
Do While Timer < Start + (TimeInMinutes * 60) - (0.5 * 60)
    DoEvents
    Loop
Application.StatusBar = "File will close in less than 30 seconds. Make sure to save."

Do While Timer < Start + (TimeInMinutes * 60) - (0.333 * 60)
    DoEvents
    Loop
Application.StatusBar = "File will close in less than 20 seconds. Make sure to save."

Do While Timer < Start + (TimeInMinutes * 60) - (0.167 * 60)
    DoEvents
    Loop
Application.StatusBar = "File will close in less than 10 seconds. Make sure to save."


Do While Timer < Start + (TimeInMinutes * 60)
    DoEvents
    Loop
    
Application.StatusBar = "File closed due to inactivity"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: You might be better off using `Application.OnTime` to schedule the event, rather than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your code blocks a lot. Try something like this instead:

Replace your Workbook_Open with this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ClearStatus
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"), "Warn30"
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:25"), "Warn10"
End Sub
```

Put this in a module:

```
Sub ClearStatus()
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub

Sub Warn30()
    Application.StatusBar = "File will close in less than 30 seconds. Make sure to save."
End Sub

Sub Warn10()
    Application.StatusBar = "File will close in less than 10 seconds. Make sure to save."
End Sub
```

Obviously not a complete example, but it is a start.